# maven central search not see my library new version

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin, maven-central

I successfully deployed new version of my library with version 1.15 to maven central.
For successfully i mean - i can get it via gradle, i can see in maven-metadata.xml last version set to 1.15, and i can see it in browser in path https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/mycompany/malibrary/1.15  with old versions

however maven central search http://search.maven.org/ did not able to find my new version artefacts! it only show old versions (1.10 for example)

did i miss something? it been two weeks since release to maven

Comment: Did you try to open a ticket in JIRA for the Open Source Project Repository Hosting (link [here](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH))?

Comment: @AmnonShochot, ticket created a year ago, comment says sync is activated, but current ticket state is close. Should i reopen it?

Comment: It sounds like this is a new problem, since you just published this 2 weeks ago?  If so, please open new issue in the open source hosting project, and we'll get this fixed for you.